# how to extend the expiry time of same jwt token in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, express-jwt

I have done so much google about jwt token node.js but I am unable to find out that how to extend the expiry time of jwt token during verify or in some other way.

I have tried refresh-token, it returns a new token but I want to reuse the same token instead of new token.

Suppose if we set expiry time to 10 minutes and if user will be performed some activity at 9th minute then add more ten minutes to the expiry time of  that same token. But I am unable to extend that expiry time using node.js, so please help me to extend the timespan of the same jwt token without any changes in it so that user continues with that same jwt token.

Comment: Once token is generated you can not extend time of that token because time is also encrypted in this token and if you change the time token will also be changed. For more detail please check this https://jwt.io/#debugger there is one param of time. Best solution is to use `refresh-token` approach.

Comment: But in case of refresh-token, we get a new token as I mentioned in or question also. So, Is there any way to get that same token with extended expiry time ?

Comment: No, without modifying token its not possible.

Comment: Thanks Aabid for your valuable comment. So, Is there any possible way in another token mechanism to continue with the same token because it's client requirement.

Comment: What are you using for client side?

Comment: Actually, our client is saying this kind of requirements. Tha's why I discuss my problem here.

Comment: The question is not relevant and the scenario mentioned is not valid. Also i would mention doing such things leads to high security risk.

Answer (score -3):

To set expirey time in days: try this

```
var token = jwt.sign({email:'demo@gmail.com'}, "Stack", {

       expiresIn: '365d' // expires in 365 days

  });
```

Comment: Read question carefully he wants to use same token with extend time.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can I extend the expiry time of the same token ?